# Is optional or required the default for protocol methods?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols

I used to think that the default/implicit specifier for protocol methods is optional. However, in my current project I see a warning if I do not add the @optional specifier specifically. Not a big deal. I am just wondering, was it optional the default for a while, and now it is required? Or maybe I missed something while I was learning Objective-C a while ago.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@required` was always by default to gurantee, that you app won't crash if you inherit protocol and forget to implemet methods. So you should manuall set `@optional`

Answer (score 3):

From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH11-SW1)

> By default, all methods declared in a protocol are required methods.

It's always been required by default. There is no way that has changed or many things would suddenly start breaking.

Comment: If something doesn't implement a required method, does it only throw a compiler warning and not an error?

Comment: @matrixugly I think it's an error but why not try it and see?

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah, I did try it and there was no compiler error. Just a runtime crash.